# Set "From" address when using System.Net.Mail.MailMessage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, system, mailmessage

I'm trying to send a password reset email, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to specify the sender's address.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From.Address = "support@mycompany.com";
mail.To.Add(Email);
mail.Subject = "Forgot Password";
mail.Body = "<a href=\"" + url + "\">Click here to reset your password.</a>";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.SendAsync(mail, null);
```

I'm sure it's possible, so how can I accomplish this in ASP.Net?

Comment: What's your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you using MailMessage class or something else?

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. So what is wrong with your code? Does it not work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turns out I was getting ahead of myself.

Removing `Address` from `mail.From.Address` allowed me to set the value, but needed the type `MailAddress`.

Here's the solution:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("support@mycompany.com");
mail.To.Add(Email);
mail.Subject = "Forgot Password";
mail.Body = "<a href=\"" + url + "\">Click here to reset your password.</a>";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.SendAsync(mail, null);
```

Comment: Great, glad you posted your own solution.